# Command laravel not found and suspected issue in .composer folder

Tags: bash, laravel, composer-php

I've searched all over Google, obviously on StackOverflow as well but my issue seems different than all i've seen so far.

Well I'm in a process of installing Laravel Homestead and I got to the point where I need the laravel command but bash tells me **command not found**.

YES, I edited .bash_profile ( don't have .bashrc file ) with many combinations of the export statement.. the last one was export **export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH**

The thing that keeps my attention, is that I don't have a vendor folder in my .composer folder but only these 3 files :

- **cacert.pem**
- **keys.dev.pub**
- **keys.tags.pub**

I already reinstalled composer completely and I still got this configuration.

Nothing found on the internet worked for me...

Comment: Did you install laravel globally through composer? It won't be in your home directory if that's the case. The command from the docs does a global install `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`

Comment: Well my issue here is that when I do this, I get this error :   [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  The process has been signaled with signal "5".       So now I also have to figure it out

Comment: Signal 5 is coming from php . Which version of php are you using? Do you have svn installed by chance?

Comment: Thanks for helping, I'm starting to have a track, I have php 5.5 I don't know what the heck it's doing there.. I'm gonna change it then try the composer command and let you know

Comment: Yeah 5.5 is a bit dated at this point. If possible upgrade to at least 5.6, ideally 7.1.

Comment: Well updated php to 7.1 with brew, but still the same issue. When I prompt svn command it tells me this : dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libcrypto.35.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libserf-1.0.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
 so I don't know

Comment: Sounds like you have a corrupted binary or something. Try this `brew reinstall sqlite svn`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163454/discussion-between-naspy971-and-btl).

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason is that you dont have laravel installed properly.

**Follow these steps**

1.Go to the directory where you want to create project then run this command

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myProject
```

***Alternatively***

you can do

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

This will install laravel files in the temp. And then go to directory where you want to create project and run
 `laravel new myProject`

Once that's done

2. Go inside your project root folder in cmd and run this command composer `require laravel/homestead --dev` it will install homestead for your project.

There are many other ways to do so but i find this easy. If you like to try other project please check this [link here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead)